# rails render does not work properly after manually setting request.format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4. I am trying to create a dynamic form_tag with ajax

so everytime "Addsymbol" was clicked, it triggers testpage.js.erb and a new input field will be added (through render by ajax)

whereas when "Send input" was clicked, it triggers testpage.html.erb, which trigger query and return result that will be shown on screen

testpage.html.erb

```
<div id="ajaxsearchform">
<%=render 'searchform'%>
</div>
   ....code that will show @res on the browser, not important to this topic....
```

testpage.js.erb

```
$('#ajaxsearchform').html("<%=j(render('searchform'))%>");
```

_searchform.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag '/stinfos/testpage',remote:true do %>
    <%=submit_tag "Addsymbol",name:"addsymbol" %>
    .....code that handle how many input field to show up, not important to this topic....
    <%=submit_tag "Send input",name:"getresult" %></td>
<%end%>
```

controller is like this

```
  if(!params[:addsymbol].nil?)
          @numofsymbol+=1
  end

  if(!params[:getresult].nil?)
          request.format = :html
  end  

  ...code that will do the query and store result in instance variable @res...

  respond_to do |format|
                    format.js {render layout:'application';}
                    format.html {render layout:'application';}
            end
```

now addsymbol works perfectly, which add new input field without refreshing the whole page

However, when I click "Send input", it shows this

```
  Rendered stinfos/_searchform.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Stinfo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `stinfos`.* FROM `stinfos`  WHERE (symbol='SVA' OR symbol='' OR         symbol='')
  Testdatum Load (0.1ms)  SELECT symbol,stdate,x52wk_high,x52wk_low FROM `testdata`  WHERE 

  (symbol='SVA' OR symbol='' OR symbol='')
  Rendered stinfos/_testshowall.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered stinfos/testpage.html.erb within layouts/application (10.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 1109ms (Views: 1094.7ms | ActiveRecord: 5.4ms)
```

You can see that  stinfos/testpage.html.erb was successfully rendered (because of the request.format=:html), but the browser does not show query result stored in @res

The only way to show the query result is --- remove the remote:true option in form_tag --- while keep

other code exactly the same. In this case the console says

```
Rendered stinfos/_searchform.html.erb (1.7ms)
Stinfo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `stinfos`.* FROM `stinfos`  WHERE (symbol='SVA' OR symbol='' OR symbol='')
Testdatum Load (0.1ms)  SELECT symbol,stdate,x52wk_high,x52wk_low FROM `testdata`  WHERE (symbol='SVA' OR symbol='' OR symbol='')
Rendered stinfos/_testshowall.html.erb (1.9ms)
Rendered stinfos/testpage.html.erb within layouts/application (11.7ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1230ms (Views: 1121.6ms | ActiveRecord: 98.8ms)


Started GET "/assets/estimatechanges.css?body=1" for 66.216.227.139 at 2014-11-07 14:10:16 -0600


Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 66.216.227.139 at 2014-11-07 14:10:16 -0600

.....
```

However, this will not use the ajax function and so when addsymbol was clicked the screen will refresh

Please note that when remote:true is enabled, the "Started GET ..." lines were not shown

Why the render behave differently when remote:true is enabled ?

Is that because I missed any important code besides request.format=:html ?

Comment: I have figured out part of the reason, when remote:true is enabled, submit_tag will send a request that accept only text/javascript. Even if I set request.format=:html on the fly and route respond_to to render format.html, the page will not change since it only accept text/javascript.

Comment: But how can I change the request header to accept html when remote:true is enabled in form_tag ?